# Does a binary heap support the decrease-key operation?

Tags: data-structures, priority-queue

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29#Comparison_of_theoretic_bounds_for_variants, it takes Θ(logn) (which translates to O(logn)) to perform the decrease-key operation. However, there seems to be no site that includes a binary heap implementation with a decrease-key operation.

Given therefore the lack of implementations on the web, is it possible to perform the decrease-key operation in a binary heap?

Comment: I think it's a perfectly valid question he's asking...

Comment: [I implemented it in JavaScript](https://github.com/mhluska/Snakeception/blob/master/src/binaryheap.coffee).

Comment: you may be interested in [Fibonacci heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap) which have `Θ(1)` `decrease-key` operations

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured this out:

- In order to perform a decrease-key in O(logn), we have to know the location of the corresponding element in advance. A hash map and a good hash function can guarantee O(1) amortized time. After each modification, we have to update the hash map, which takes O(logn).
- After determining the location of our element, we move our element up in case it has a greater priority than its parent (in a similar manner to insertion) or down if it has a lower priority than one of its children (in a similar manner to deletion) and update the modified elements' locations in the hash map.

Comment: I think it's the other way around. The update of hash map takes O(1) while decrease-key takes O(lg(n)).

Comment: Update the hash map is O(log n) because you have to update it for every `swap( parent, child )` operation. There are O(log n) such operation in a `decreasekey` operation.