# Implementing Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm using a red/black tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dijkstra, shortest-path, red-black-tree

I know that Dijkstra's algorithm in reality is implemented using a Fibonacci heap. But can it also be implemented using a red black tree and still have a worst-case running time of O(m log n)?

Comment: See http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/shaikat/papers/TR-07-54.pdf for actual ways on how to implement it efficiently.

Comment: Have a look into this related question http://stackoverflow.com/q/14252582/194609

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For starters, it's rare to actually see Dijkstra's algorithm implemented with a Fibonacci heap.  Although the Fibonacci heap gives great asymptotic performance (O(m + n log n)), in practice it has such high constant factors that other types of heaps are more efficient.

As to your question - yes, you could use a red-black tree as a priority queue to get O(m log n) performance.  This works because you can find the minimum element in a red-black tree in O(log n) time and simulate a decrease-key operation on the tree in time O(log n) by doing a deletion followed by an insertion.  However, this is probably not as efficient as using a standard binary heap, since the red-black tree has worse locality of reference and more memory overhead.  More generally, you always can use a balanced binary search tree whenever you need a priority queue, though usually doing so is overkill.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I would not say that Dijkstra's algorithm is implemented using a Fibonacci heap. In fact any heap will do although Fiboncci has the best amortized complexity for different operations(keep in mind though this only shows in **really** huge graphs). Again using red-black tree will achieve the same computational complexity but will have higher constant as working with red-black trees is more complex.

What you need for this algorithm is only to be able to get the minimum element from a given set. That is what a heap is meant for and thus it is best suited for this problem. A red-black tree can do a lot of other stuff and thus is more complex and preforms worse in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. Yes, you can use Red-Black tree to implement, here is an example below:

https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Java