# Is it possible to implement a min-priority queue with a heap, or is binary heap needed?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, heap, priority-queue

For my assignment, I have been working on a satnav system and I am using an adjacency list to store all of the mapping data.

I therefor want to implement dijkstras algorithm for my path planning functions but I need to first implement a min-priority queue. Is is possible to do this using a regular heap, or is a binary one needed?

Comment: related (possible duplicate?): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252582/how-can-i-use-binary-heap-in-the-dijkstra-algorithm

Answer (score 2):

It seems you mean `regular heap` as memory region used for dynamic memory allocation. This term has no relation to the term `heap` as data structure (binary heap is particular case), which represents a set of values, ordered in specific manner

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a min-priority queue with a regular (array-based) heap very easily, but Dijkstra's algorithm requires support for an additional operation:  you have to be able to find any given item and dynamically lower its priority.

An array-based heap doesn't normally come with an efficient way to find any item except the root, so you need to add a way to do that.

An easy way is to maintain a 2nd array that contains the index of each item in the heap array (or -1 if the item isn't in the heap).  You have to update this array whenever you add, remove, or swap heap items.